# How to save and load System.IO.Stream objects with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, telerik, persistence

I want to save the "view" status of my wpf application using the Telerik's PersistenceFramework.

I can save and load the stream on-the-fly, [like in the docs examples](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radpersistenceframework/features/persistence-framework-save-stream), but I need to store the `status` stream object on database.

I'm currently trying with no luck those functions:

```
public static void SaveGridStatus(System.IO.Stream stream)
{
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        TestViewStatus t = new TestViewStatus { GridStatus = ms.ToArray() };
        context.TestViewStatuses.Add(t);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public static Stream LoadGridStatus()
{
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    {
        TestViewStatus t = (from d in context.TestViewStatuses
                select d).FirstOrDefault();
        return t.GridStatus;
    }
}
```

where TestViewStatus.GridStatus is a `VARBINARY(MAX)`

Something is saved in the database, but when I try to load it in my control using the persistence framework nothing happens

**edit:**

code to load stream into control, as requested

```
private void SaveGridLayout_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PersistenceManager manager = new PersistenceManager();
    this.stream = manager.Save(this.BrowseProjectGrid);
    SaveBrowseGridStatus(this.stream);
    this.EnsureLoadState();
}

private void LoadGridLayout_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.stream.Position = 0L;
    PersistenceManager manager = new PersistenceManager();
    manager.Load(this.BrowseProjectGrid, LoadBrowseGridStatus());
    this.EnsureLoadState();
}
```

(i want to point out that it works correctly if i use a local `Stream` object to save and retrieve the view status)

Comment: Show code how you are loading stream into control

Comment: the code is almost the same of the linked example, but i added it to the question...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, that issue is in

```
public static Stream LoadGridStatus()
{
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    {
        TestViewStatus t = (from d in context.TestViewStatuses
                select d).FirstOrDefault();
        return t.GridStatus;
    }
}
```

Replace it with

```
public static Stream LoadGridStatus()
{
    using (MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    {
        TestViewStatus t = (from d in context.TestViewStatuses
                select d).FirstOrDefault();
        return new MemoryStream(t.GridStatus);
    }
}
```

The change is that varbinary(max) is being loaded from DB and put into Stream.